# how does Spring know from the jsp what controller to use?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have this in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Dispatching handled by StaticFilter -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have this in dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Activates scanning of @Repository -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pronto.mexp" />

    <!-- View Resolver for JSPs -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="rc"/>
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have this in AlertsController:

```
@Controller
public class AlertsController {

    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private AlertManager alertManager;

    @RequestMapping("/alerts")
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // display in view
        logger.info("Returning alerts view");

        List<Alert> alerts = alertManager.getAlerts();
        request.setAttribute("alerts", alerts);

        return new ModelAndView();
    }

    public void setAlertManager(AlertManager alertManager) {
        this.alertManager = alertManager;
    }
}
```

And I have this in alerts.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<h3>ALERTS</h3>

<table border="1">
<c:forEach var="alert" items="${alerts}">
    <tr>
    <td>${alert.hostname}</td>
    <td>${alert.message}</td>
    <td>${alert.program}</td>
    <td><fmt:formatDate value="${alert.date}" dateStyle="medium"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

But when I start the app up and point my browser to localhost:8080/alerts.jsp, I get only the header "ALERTS" and nothing else. It's like Spring doesn't know to use the AlertsController. I know I'm leaving out some key config but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it opposite of what you're supposed to. It's not the JSP that knows which controller to use, but the Controller knows which view (JSP) to render. The controller is executed by it's url mapping, which is defined in the `@RequestMapping` attribute. When you access your JSP directly like that, you're not going through Spring at all. So try using the url `http://localhost:8080/context/alerts` instead, replacing `context` with the context path of the web application.

Comment: Thanks! One more question - where do I find the context path of the web app?

Comment: If you can reach your JSP with `localhost:8080/alert.jsp`, then it's blank. But usually you configure this when deploying the application.

Comment: So how do you know which controller rendered the JSP

Comment: For what purpose?

Answer (score 0):

My coworker pointed out my dispatcher-servlet.xml was also missing the mvc instruction to scan for annotations in my Controllers:

```
<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

So even when I pointed my browser at `localhost:8080/alerts` (since I have no context path configured), it was still failing. Once I added the mvc instruction, the controller was invoked, and the dynamic content was sent to the jsp.

Comment: But I'm going to give credit to @NilsH for his half of the answer since my coworker refuses to sign up for a SO account. IDK why!

Answer (score 0):

One line Answer : you are calling it in wrong way you have to call /alerts not alerts.jsp

but why you are getting this empty page, because you are calling jsp direct without setting values by controller, you are putting Jsp files under root

```
<property name="prefix" value="/"/>
```

so that it is accessible it is better to put it in WEB-INF to prevent direct access

```
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"/>
```

Comment: i was getting the empty page because the controller was not being invoked. see my answer, above. but as you, and NilsH before you, noted, i was calling it wrong / thinking about it backward.

Comment: "controller was not being invoked" becuse you are calling "/alerts.jsp" while controller is listening for "/alerts" @RequestMapping("/alerts")

Comment: sorry, but as i mentioned in my answer, above, even when i called "/alerts" it was still failing. the controller was not being invoked because Spring didn't know to look for annotations for controllers.

Comment: you mean component scan was not configured probably, OK, it is common mistake :D